# Using django-mptt with django auth_user

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-mptt

I am trying to create a user tree using `django-mptt`. I have `auth_user` table and a one-to-one mapping table `UserProperties` which has a foreign key of `auth_user`.
I added `TreeForeignKey` of django-mptt in `UserProperties` model(`parent` column) on User table. But it is failing while creating objects with following error:

```
'User' object has no attribute 'is_root_node'
```

Comment: Are you using recent django which allow custom user models?  This would allow you to combine User and UserProperties and might solve your problem.

Comment: I am using django-1.4.10 which supports custom user models.

Comment: I was thinking of the one introduced in 1.5 see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/releases/1.5/#configurable-user-model

Answer (score 2):

The method (not attribute) 'is_root_node()' is valid on query-items

```
item = Class.objects.get()
```

or in iterator or list expression:

```
[item.is_root_node() for item in Class.objects.filter(name = 'name')]
```

But to address your question properly, could you give us the code for your model and your query, please.